# Twig IF statement not working

Tags: twig

I am trying to use a simple if statement in Twig. However it doesn't seem to be working properly. The variable emailActivation is certainly being loaded into Twig properly as can be seen from the first line of the output in all cases.

However the if statement is behaving very oddly - for example it works as expected when the variable is false and being tested against 1 (*case 2*) but not when it is false and tested against 'false' (*case 1*).

Conversely when the variable is true the if statement works when the variable is tested against 'true' (*case 3*) but not when tested against 1 (*case 4*).

**I only show the tests against 1 as a workaround I attempted**, really I think the problem lies in (*case 1*). (*case 5*) and (*case 4*) suggest the numbers are being evaluated as boolean.

I also thought it could perhaps be an issue to do with caching, but to my knowledge I have set Twig up not to use a cache. Even if Twig is caching the problem still occurs on the first page load and when the browser is restarted. I have tried in IE and Firefox though again I don't think the browser is really relevant to the problem which lies in Twig itself as far as I can tell.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

***Case 1***  emailActivation = false

**Twig code**

```
{{ emailActivation }}
{% if emailActivation == true %}
    feature disabled
{% else %}
    other content
{% endif %}
```

**Output**
false
feature disabled

***Case 2*** emailActivation = false

**Twig code**

```
{{ emailActivation }}
{% if emailActivation == 1 %}
    feature disabled
{% else %}
    other content
{% endif %}
```

**Output**
false
other content

***Case 3*** emailActivation = true

**Twig code**

```
{{ emailActivation }}
{% if emailActivation == true %}
    feature disabled
{% else %}
    other content
{% endif %}
```

**Output**
true
feature disabled

***Case 4*** emailActivation = true

**Twig code**

```
{{ emailActivation }}
{% if emailActivation == 1 %}
    feature disabled
{% else %}
    other content
{% endif %}
```

**Output**
true
other content

***Case 5*** emailActivation = true

**Twig code**

```
{{ emailActivation }}
{% if emailActivation == 0 %}
    feature disabled
{% else %}
    other content
{% endif %}
```

**Output**
true
feature disabled

Comment: emailActivation is a string ? Because I see false or true in the result of `{{ emailActivation }}` [instead of nothing or 1 [or something else] first time i see this]]

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 That makes a lot of sense! I can't test to confirm atm but will tomorrow. It is odd that there is a different result in case 4 and 5 though if it is a string. Thanks

Comment: Yes It was just a thinking not an answer, and still strange I don't understand why case 5...

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 You are correct it was a string. I'm new to stack exchange but I think you need to post that as an answer for me to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One detail make think that emailActivation could be a string.

The output of `{{ emailActivation }}` is `false` or `true`, but I think that a boolean return something else *(~ nothing or `1` ~)*.

The fact to test the condition as being a string should resolve the problem.

One way will be *(for simply a string, not a big content)*:

```
{{ emailActivation }}
{{ (emailActivation == 'true') ? 'feature disabled' : 'other content' }}
```

Friendly

Answer (score 1):

try `same as` it is equivalent to === in PHP
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/sameas.html